# What academic evidence is there of the pronunciation of gn as ɲn in Vulgar Latin?

Tags: vulgar-latin

I've come across a fairly frequent claim that gn was pronounced as ɲn in vulgar Latin. However, I haven't been able to find any kind of academic sources to back that up. I've found a few sources (and questions answered here) specific to Classical Latin, but none for Vulgar Latin.

I hate to put forth something as a known fact without having any kind of evidence to back me up, so I'd like to know more. Are there any good sources for this claim? How do we know that gn was pronounced as ɲn in vulgar latin?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The main evidence is the evolution in Romance languages. Latin GN generally becomes `/ɲ/`, like Spanish *maño*; in languages that preserve contrastive consonant length, it becomes a geminate `/ɲɲ/`, as in Italian *magno*.

We know it was originally something like `/gn/`, due to etymology: the first half of *magnus* also appears in *magis*, for example. And the most plausible path for `/gn/` to become `/ɲɲ/` involves the first half assimilating in manner, then both halves assimilating in place.

Comment: Thank you! Some places I've read that /gn/ might have first evolved into /ŋn/, then /ɲn/, and finally /ɲɲ/. Do you believe this is supported?

Comment: @Lind That seems very reasonable; I'm not sure if there's any direct evidence for how the path went, though.

Comment: I find this latin digraph weird, because in Portuguese it became "nh" (it sounds exactly like the Spanish "ñ") in some words like "lenha/lignum, but ligneo/ligneus, it kept the "gn".

Comment: @Lind: Hmm I'm having trouble pronouncing /ɲn/, is that really a thing?

Comment: @ManuelCauãRebouças: Perhaps some words were later borrowings from Latin?

Comment: Cerberus, actually, a few words wich latin roots changed the "gn" to "nh" in Portuguese. I never learnt why.

Comment: @Manuel /ɲ/ (that is, ⟨nh⟩) is the regular outcome. If a word has ⟨gn⟩, such as _ígneo_, that means it’s a later (≈ Mediaeval or later) re-borrowing from Classical Latin.

Comment: @Cerberus I recall seeing a suggestion (though I don’t recall the evidence for it) that it went /ɡn/ > /ŋn/ > /ŋɲ/ (i.e., dorsal velar + laminal alveolar/dental assimilated to dorsal velar + dorsal palatal) > /ɲɲ/.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet: That sounds far more plausible to me. Except that I cannot understand the last one, with the same consonant twice?

Comment: @Cerberus That’s just the more-or-less end result, /ɲː/, as still found in Italian (later shortened in Spanish, Portuguese, French, etc.).

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet: Ahh so the same symbol twice doesn't mean the same sound twice, but just a lengthening, OK, then it makes sense.